# Non-parametric testing for three way interaction effects

Tags: statistics, data-modeling, interaction, statistical-test

I'm looking for the appropriate test to perform to determine if there is a three way interaction effect on my (non-parametric) likert-scale data.

My data currently has a dependent variable with values from 1-7 on a likert scale. The study includes three dependent variables, all of which are nominal. I need to check whether there is a relationship between these three that would explain the pattern of responses in the dependent variable.

Something like Scheirer Ray Hare but including a three-way interaction? Or should I just go for a non-parametric model? If so, what model would you suggest?

TIA!

Comment: Interesting question, however, it is off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.